# Disable VLC's MPRIS plugin

Tags: gnome, vlc, extension

I'd like if possible to disable VLC from using the MPRIS interface. I use the Gnome-shell media player extension and it also includes VLC in it which i dont want to.
Does anyone know how to do that? (disable vlc's mpris support or hide vlc from the media player gnome-shell extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Preferences* in VLC. Click on *All* in *Show settings* in the bottom.

Go to *Control interface* under *Interface* and uncheck the option next to *D-Bus control interface* and save the changes.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately thats already unchecked but the media player extension still notices vlc

Comment: No but i thought this might be a problem on my setup and not with vlc's settings.

Comment: Alright. It was confusing for me since you accepted the answer without leaving any comment.